# Can't find elements inside iframe on Safari using Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe, safari, protractor

We have an html page with an iframe. As you can see in the code below, iframe is generated by javascript (this is simplified version, since we cannot show the production code). Our goal is to write end-to-end tests using Protractor. We would like to assure the presence of div element inside iframe (the test is also given below). The problem is that the test is passing on Chrome on mac OS Mojave, but falling on Safari 12.0.2.
If iframe is not generated by JS, the test is passed on Safari.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

function domOnLoad() {
    const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

    const iframeElement = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframeElement.frameBorder = 0;
    iframeElement.seamless = true;
    iframeElement.scrolling = 'no';

    rootElement.appendChild(iframeElement);

    const divElement  = document.createElement('div');
    divElement.id = 'iframeRoot';

    const textElement = document.createTextNode('Test Iframe');
    divElement.appendChild(textElement);

    iframeElement.contentDocument.body.appendChild(divElement);

    console.log(rootElement);
}

    </script>
</head>
    <body onload="domOnLoad()">
        <div id="root">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

describe('Test should have', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

    it('div inside iframe with an id iframeRoot', () => {
        browser.get('http://localhost:5000/examples/iframe.html/');
        browser.switchTo().frame(0);

        var divInsideIframe =  $('#iframeRoot');
        expect(divInsideIframe.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to switch to iframe first

```
browser.switchTo().frame('iframe');
```

then try to find element which is in `iframe`

I hope this will help you

Comment: We are already switching to iframe by index:

browser.switchTo().frame(0);